# Ftp user that has access to every file and directory

Tags: server, ftp, vsftpd

How can I create a user for FTP that has access to every directory and file to write it I'm using the VSFTPD.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose that you could make your ftp user root.  BTW - this would be a terrible idea.  Perhaps you should re-write your question and think a little harder about what you are trying to accomplish.  Under no circumstances, should you give the permission to write to any directory to anyone that you do not trust as a root user.

Comment: @CharlesGreen it would only be used by me once I have everything set up would be deleted. I do have an account that has root directory but I keep on getting that I do not have permissions to edit files

Comment: This seems like a classic [XY Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Your *real* problem seems to be configuring a remote system. Unfortunately, your preferred solution (FTP as root) is both unsafe AND unworkable --it fights layers of security protections that have been applied over decades precisely to prevent somebody from using FTP to place root-owned files. Consider asking a question about your *real* problem -- how to safely and securely configure a remote system.

Comment: Okay. Well, when I create a user that has access to say one directory that has a lot of other folders inside of it, it only gives me access to do stuff and not directory. But in reality, they're still several other folders inside that directory that also need to be edited. How can I make it to where they're all included?